# mysql convert string to int not working(with pdo)

Tags: mysql

I want to convert memberID from string to int first then do other operation in mysql but it seems that only num 3 sql work,how can i fix it?
otherwise,I have a question that why I input memberID by php int type but mysql insert it as string?

```
select hasGivePoint from posts where postID=:postID and json_search(hasGivePoint,'one',(convert(:memberID ,signed))) is not null;


update
posts
set
$pointName=$pointName-1,hasGivePoint=JSON_REMOVE(hasGivePoint,replace(json_search(hasGivePoint,'one',
convert(:memberID ,signed)),'\"',''))
WHERE postID=:postID;
";


update posts set $pointName=$pointName+1,hasGivePoint=JSON_ARRAY_APPEND(hasGivePoint,'$',convert(:memberID ,signed)) where postID=:postID;
```